# Static Members in a Global class

Tags: class, static, typescript

```
export class Globals
{
   static m_Name : string = "Hello world";
   static m_Version : number = 1.0;
   static m_Canvas : HTMLCanvasElement = null;
   static m_Foo : Foo = null;
}

public OnDocumentLoad() : void
{
     Globals.m_Canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     Globals.m_Foo = new Foo(m_Name, m_Version);
}
```

Is this acceptable use of `static` in TypeScript? I'm unsure of what static is doing in this case other than making the member variables class members that everyone can access regardless of instance. But, for example, is `m_Foo` and `m_Canvas` valid instances within the Globals class, kind of like singletons so to speak (without any undefined checking and presumably anytime after OnDocumentLoad of course)

Originally I didn't have Globals as a class and they were just generic var declarations I had in a .ts file I was referencing everywhere. But I wanted to organize them into a nice little Globals class. This works in my experience testing it so far, but I wanted to see if there was anything I was missing about what `static` is doing here.

The most I found on the subject was here in the Specification:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

> Member declarations with a static modifier are called static member declarations. Static property 
>   member declarations declare properties in the constructor function type (section 8.2.5), and must specify 
>   names that are unique among all static property member declarations in the containing class, with the 
>   exception that static get and set accessor declarations may pairwise specify the same name.
>   Note that the declaration spaces of instance and static property members are separate. Thus, it is possible 
>   to have instance and static property members with the same name

From that I gleam that you can make an instance of Globals and its members will have a different meaning from just calling the `Globals.m_Name` for example, but I don't intend to do that here.

Comment: I'm hesitant because I don't want to make any assumptions about static that I've learned, from say, C# and try to apply it to Javascript/Typescript :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a namespace object, use `module`:

```
export module Globals
{
   export var m_Name : string = "Hello world";
   export var m_Version : number = 1.0;
   export var m_Canvas : HTMLCanvasElement = null;
   export var m_Foo : Foo = null;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: difference: modules are open ended (members can be added to). Classes are not. Thats the big one.

Comment: What is the difference between an object and a function? module -> object, class -> function.